# Multiple datasheets in crossfilter + d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter

I am Newbie to this crossfilter and d3.js..Data for my project is loaded from my project directory,i have csv files for data.When loading single data sheet(single csv file) and giving input to crossfilter its fine,its working well..

But when i have 2 sheets how can i combine into single and give input to crossfilter??

Corresponding code:

```
 d3.csv("vc5.csv", function (data) {
     crossfilter(data);
    //Doing calculation
    //All charts calculations and chart display
    });
```

But now my requirement is,i have to read data from 2 datasheets(2 csv files) having common field "Name".

My requirement:

```
d3.csv("vc5.csv", function (data) {
   d3.csv("xxx.csv",function(data1){
    crossfilter()-------------------------->I have to combine 2 datas into single object and i have to pass to crossfilter. 
    //Doing calculation
    //All charts calculations and chart display
    });
    });
```

Help me to achieve this?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Pure JS might do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15700658/2463468

Comment: Thanks @benjaminjosephw  ..I saw that post already..But my problem is that the length of 2 sheets are not same for me..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `add` method: https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-crossfilter_add

Step 3 in this answer is what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/21194072/916734