# dc.js: ReduceSum with multiple CSVs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

This is a follow-up to another StackOverflow [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192436/loading-multiple-csv-in-dc-js-adding-a-value-and-concatenating-the-results-int) with creating charts  with multiple CSVs into a single dc.js dashboard.

I followed the instructions and my charts are working. However, what is not working is the `numberDisplay` elements. What I'm suspecting is that since I'm tabulating the totals of two CSVs, I would have to adjust the `groupAll.reduceSum()` function, but I'm unsure how. An example of my code is below

```
//using queue.js to load data
var q = queue()
  .defer(d3.csv, "data1.csv")
  .defer(d3.csv, "data2.csv");

  q.await(function(error, data1, data2){

  //initiatizing crossfilter and ingesting data
  var ndx = crossfilter();
  ndx.add(data1.map(function(d){
    return { age: d.age,
             gender: d.gender,
             scores: +d.scores,
             total: +d.total,
             type: 'data1'};
    }));

  ndx.add(data2.map(function(d){
    return { age: d.age,
             gender: d.gender,
             scores: +d.scores,
             total: +d.total,
             type: 'data2'};
    }));

//initializing charts
totalDisplay = dc.numberDisplay("#total-display");
totalScores = dc.numberDisplay("#total-scores");

//groupAll function to sum up the values
var scoresGroup = ndx.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d) {
          d.scores;
        });
        var totalGroup = ndx.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d) { 
          d.total;
        });

//parameters for the number display. Currently it is returning NaN
totalDisplay
        .formatNumber(d3.format(","))
        .valueAccessor(function(d) {
            return d;
        })
        .group(totalGroup);

totalScores
        .formatNumber(d3.format(",f"))
        .valueAccessor(function(d) {
            return d;
        })
        .group(scoresGroup);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A fiddle would help, and/or any errors you are seeing in the JavaScript console. Be more specific than "it doesn't work" - is it errors or bad values?

Comment: Right now, it's just simply returning NaN values, where I stated it in my comments. There are no errors in the console, it's just returning the sums of the specified columns across multiple CSV files. I'll work on making a workable jsfiddle.

Comment: I see. First put a break point on `return d;` below your comment and see if you can fix the accessor

Comment: The other thing to check is that `scoresGroup.value()` and `totalGroup.value()` are not themselves `NaN`. If those are wrong, then you want to go back to your data and make sure that `scores` and `total` are actually all numbers. It's all about getting to know the debugger built into your browser!

Comment: I have checked the `scoresGroup.value()` and `totalGroup.value()` and they ended up `NaN`. I've also confirmed that the columns of interests are all numeric. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `return` in order to return values from functions!

```
var scoresGroup = ndx.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d) {
      d.scores;
});
var totalGroup = ndx.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d) { 
      d.total;
});
```

should be

```
var scoresGroup = ndx.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d) {
      return d.scores;
});
var totalGroup = ndx.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d) { 
      return d.total;
});
```

Otherwise, you will end up summing `undefined` and `undefined` is Not a Number. :-)

Comment: It is a common mistake. In many programming languages, the last expression is the result. Glad I could help.