# dc.js with crossfilter and d3, how to load multiple csv files at once, without knowing how many files the user will upload

Tags: d3.js, queue, dc.js, crossfilter

I know some answers that can handle multiple csv files when you know how many files would be uploaded.

This is the code to get the file name one by one, and put the file into queue.

```
var q = queue();
$('#files').change(function(){
    var fileNames = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++){
        fileNames += ", " + this.files[i].name;
        .defer(d3.csv, this.files[i].name);
    }
}
```

My question is how to loop the data inside the queue and add it to the crossfilter.

```
q.await(function(error, q1data, q2data) {}
```

How can I see what is inside of the queue, use the developer tool of Google chrome.

I have seen an example https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/examples/composite.html

But this one only handle when you know how many file are there.

Here is a similar question but this is not what I want.
[Loading multiple CSV in DC.js, adding a value, and concatenating the results into a single dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192436/loading-multiple-csv-in-dc-js-adding-a-value-and-concatenating-the-results-int)

Comment: What determines how many files there are? Are you trying to load the files before you know how many there will be?

Comment: My web application has a button to allow user to upload the files, the user can load 1 or more files at once.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "awaitAll" instead of "await", because the "callback(error, files){}" function will contain all the files you uploaded as an array.

[Here](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue#queue_awaitAll) is the help documents and [demo](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1696080).

Comment: Agree. To be precise, you could also use `.await()` but it would be annoying because you'd have to iterate over [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) - `.awaitAll()` will give the results to you in a convenient array.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have got what I want after reading your suggestion.

Comment: @Kreedz Happy to help!