# How to merge two .csv files in javascript?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have **two** .csv files like that example:

```
date,type,brand,model,price
2014-11-27,  electric, tesla, model s , 100000
2014-11-27,  diesel, bmw, m3, 90000 
2014-12-13,  hybrid, toyota, yaris , 20000
```

**How can I merge these files for make only one object?**

Two files has the first row with names of columns, it's possible to delete? Or add it if I get the files without that first row?

Comment: see this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700658/combining-two-csvs-d3

Comment: @suchit I tried but only works if the data is different. I my case I would like to add at the end of array like adding data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:It will solve your problem.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var newArray = [];
    d3.csv("test.csv", function(error, data) {// with header..
        data.forEach(function(d) {


                newArray.push(d);
        });

        });

        d3.csv("test1.csv", function(error, data2) {// without header..
            data2.forEach(function(d2) {


                    newArray.push(d2);
            });

            });
        console.log(newArray);
    });
```

for info see here:http://www.d3noob.org/2014/02/how-to-import-data-from-csv-file-with.html

Comment: @Lins if you are using header in second file also then skip it in foreach for first time in second d3.csv.

Comment: Thank you @suchit for your help. Finally I got the response in that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041758/how-to-insert-a-header-in-csv-object-data-for-manage-with-d3-js for merge two files without header.