# How to insert a header in csv object data for manage with d3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm getting data from csv files for manage with d3.js. Now I would like get the data without head and insert that by JavaScript code. Example with head:

```
date,type,brand,model,price
2014-11-27,  electric, tesla, model s , 100000
2014-11-27,  diesel, bmw, m3, 90000 
2014-12-13,  hybrid, toyota, yaris , 20000
```

I want to get data without header like:

```
2014-11-27,  electric, tesla, model s , 100000
2014-11-27,  diesel, bmw, m3, 90000 
2014-12-13,  hybrid, toyota, yaris , 20000
```

I get the data like this:

```
d3.csv("fileOrURLpath", function(error, data) {...});
```

I tried to insert header making an array and pushing the header in [0] like:

```
cars[0]= {
      date:"",
      type:"",
      brand:"",
      model:"",
      price:""
        };
```

It doesn't work. Only for first in [0].

Is there any way to add a header? Without I can't do nothing else.

**EDITED**

If the file has no header, I can't use d3.csv. Thanks @LarsKotthoff for the information.

Now I tried that:

```
var headers = ["date","type","brand","model","price"].join(",");

d3.text("myPath", function(error, data) {
  data = d3.csv.parse(headers + data); ... });
```

but still not working fine. The result is something like that:

```
 Object
    " 177 ": undefined
    "  7": undefined
    " seat": undefined
    " toledo": undefined
    model: " bengaluru"
    brand: " in"
    date: Sat Dec 13 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Hora estándar romance)
    type: 7
    index: 0
    price: NaN
    price2014-11-27: " 160 "
```

Comment: If the file has no header, you can't use `d3.csv` anymore. You'd have to retrieve the file with e.g. `d3.text` and then parse the lines as CSV yourself. It's much easier to leave the header in place.

Comment: Yes I see it few minutes ago thanks. But I tried to do something like that:
`var headers = ["date","type","brand","model","price"].join(",");

d3.text("myPath", function(error, data) {

data = d3.csv.parse(headers + data);`
but it makes crazy and the output is not correct and fails. Any idea for fix it?

Comment: You need to add a line break after the headers.

Comment: What you mean? How I can do that?

Comment: Ok. I undertand! Thanks! `data = d3.csv.parse(headers +"\n"+ data);`

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Thanks to @LarsKotthoff for your help.

Finally I get my data like this:

```
// My header
var headers = ["date","type","brand","model","price"].join(",");

// First I get the file or URL data like text
d3.text("myPath", function(error, data) {
  // Then I add the header and parse to csv
  data = d3.csv.parse(headers +"\n"+ data); ... });
```

Hope that it helps!